# Can one search the SQL Server audit log with keyword and/or wildcard search?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2012, audit-logging

Using SQL Server 2012.

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280765.aspx). Does it solve your problem?